# C# Check if a UILabel is not null not work

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a litte problem with this if statement:

```
if (selectedlabel.Text!=null|| selectedlabel.Text!=""|| selectedlabel!=null)
{
    basketID = int.Parse(selectedlabel.Text); //nullpointer Value Can not be null
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

I have set a breakpoint and I see the `selectedlabel.Text` is null:

[image]

Comment: Did you enter inside `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should check for nulls (because you're trying to access object's instance fields/properties) :

```
if(selectedlabel != null)
// or
if(!ReferenceEquals(selectedlabel, null))
```

Then what you're doing is just checking if string is null or empty ( on which c# has buil-in methods ) : `string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedlabel.Text)`

Now you just have to connect these using `&&` operator which checks if both are true, but fails if first check is `false`. Knowing that it will fall back when first condition is not met you can combine this into :

```
if (!ReferenceEquals(selectedlabel, null) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedlabel.Text))
{
    // your code here
}
```

But another issue is `basketID = int.Parse(selectedlabel.Text);`. As i often says **leave some margin for errors** which means do not assume that user is smart ( better way! always assume that user is dumb as hell ) so instead of putting a number, user will input something like "please enter number 123 here" and it will kill your application.

To get rid of this just `TryParse` instead:

```
int.TryParse(selectedlabel.Text, out basketID);
```

Okay so combining **ALL** of the above, the result should be something like :

```
if (!ReferenceEquals(selectedlabel, null) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedlabel.Text))
{
    if(!int.TryParse(selectedlabel.Text, out basketID))
    {
        // user entered text that is unconvertible to int
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: And thanks for the suggestion with int.TryParse(selectedlabel.Text, out basketID); 
The user can not enter anything. It's always a Number. This Number is generated by a UIPicker (Xamarin for IOS).
So there should be no problems :-)

Comment: @Andreas: i'd use `int.TryParse` anyway because it also works with passing `null`. Then the code becomes very readable and concise: `if(int.TryParse(selectedlabel?.Text, out basketID)){// here basketID is initialized}`. This handles both, that the label is null and the label-text is null.

Answer (score 6):

You use `||` instead of the correct `&&`

```
if (selectedlabel != null && selectedlabel.Text != null && selectedlabel.Text != "")
{
    basketID = int.Parse(selectedlabel.Text); 
}
```

But this is more concise and works too:

```
if (selectedlabel != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedlabel.Text))
{
    basketID = int.Parse(selectedlabel.Text); 
}
```

Use `int.TryParse` to ensure that it's a valid integer:

```
int basketID;
if(selectedlabel != null && int.TryParse(selectedlabel.Text, out basketID))
{
    //  ...
}
```

With C#6 you can also use the [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx):

```
int basketID;
if(int.TryParse(selectedlabel?.Text, out basketID))
{
    //  ...
}
```

Comment: You can mention about C# 6, too.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedlabel?.Text))
{
    basketID = int.Parse(selectedlabel.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your if statement should be equal to null if you want it to check for null, then it should be this

```
if (selectedlabel.Text==null|| selectedlabel.Text!=""|| selectedlabel!=null)
{
    basketID = int.Parse(selectedlabel.Text); //nullpointer Value Can not be null
}
```

else it will not display the error you are trying to avoid. 
hope it helps